# generate xml from java and sql query

Tags: java, xml, oracle, dom4j

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT inst.*
FROM
  (SELECT ROWNUM AS r,
    b.name INSTNAME,
    ICC.INSTITUTE_ID,
    ICC.COURSE_ID,
    c.name INSTCOURSE
  FROM INSTITUTE_COURSE_CATEGORY ICC,
    INSTITUTE a,
    MEMBER b,
    INSTITUTE_COURSE c
  WHERE ICC.CATEGORY_ID = 47
  AND ICC.INSTITUTE_ID  = a.id
  AND ICC.INSTITUTE_ID  = c.institute_id
  AND ICC.COURSE_ID     = c.id
  AND a.member_id       = b.id
  )inst
WHERE inst.r BETWEEN 1 AND 10
```

to produce following result:

```
  R     INSTNAME                             INSTITUTE_ID   COURSE_ID   INSTCOURSE                                                                 
    1   Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement     167           1134      Post Graduate Diploma in Management                                        
    2   Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement     167           1135      Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Marketing)                      
    3   Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement     167           1136      Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)             
    4   Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement     167           1138      Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking & Financial Services)   
    5   University of Delhi                     182           4283      Bachelor of Business Studies                                     
    6   University of Delhi                     182           4285      Bachelor of Commerce (Pass)                                      
    7   University of Delhi                     182           4291      Bachelor of Commerce (Honours)                                   
    8   University of Delhi                     182           4366      Master of Commerce                                           
    9   Acharya Narendra Dev College            183            812      B.Com. (Hons)                                                    
    10  Aditi Mahavidyalaya                     184            829      B.Com (Pass)
```

From the above query result, I had to make the following xml in java:

```
<Root>
  <INSTITUTE>
    <ID>167</ID>
    <NAME>Asia Pacific Instiute Of Mangement</Name>  
    <COURSES>
        <COURSE>
           <ID>1134</ID>
           <NAME>Post Graduate Diploma in Management</NAME>
        </COURSE>
         ..more
    </COURSES>
   </INSTITUTE>
    ..more
</Root>
```

For Example:

```
There are 4 Courses that belongs to InstituteID(167). 

The problem I am facing is how to make 4 child nodes (Courses Nodes(1134,1135,1136,1138)) under a single `<INSTITUTE>`  node
```

and subsequently make other courses node  under their respective

`<INSITUTE>`

nodes.

Kindly provide suggestion...

Comment: Well what exactly is the problem? What have you tried, and how did it fail? Note that it would be best if you could show a much smaller example (fewer columns) that still demonstrates whatever aspect you're finding difficult.

Comment: city,state,country,member,institute, member,course all are tables?

Comment: @mtariq:yes,they all are tables.

Comment: @JonSkeet:I hope question is now better explained.

Comment: I am using dom4j to convert xml from java.

Comment: @springpro: Not really - surely you just need to group by InstituteID within your Java code. What have you tried, and where did you get a problem?

Comment: @JonSkeet: How to group by InstituteID within the Java code?

Comment: @springpro: Any way you like, e.g. creating a `Map<Integer, Result>`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Oracle's XMLQuery functionality to produce the XML in one go. To illustrate this, I first simulate your setup by creating four tables:

```
SQL> create table member (id,name)
  2  as
  3  select 1, 'Asia Pacific Institute Of Management' from dual union all
  4  select 2, 'University of Delhi' from dual union all
  5  select 3, 'Acharya Narendra Dev College' from dual union all
  6  select 4, 'Aditi Mahavidyalaya' from dual
  7  /

Table created.

SQL> create table institute (id, member_id)
  2  as
  3  select 167, 1 from dual union all
  4  select 182, 2 from dual union all
  5  select 183, 3 from dual union all
  6  select 184, 4 from dual
  7  /

Table created.

SQL> create table institute_course (id,institute_id,name)
  2  as
  3  select 1134, 167, 'Post Graduate Diploma in Management' from dual union all
  4  select 1135, 167, 'Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Marketing)' from dual union all
  5  select 1136, 167, 'Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)' from dual union all
  6  select 1137, 167, 'Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking & Financial Services)' from dual union all
  7  select 4283, 182, 'Bachelor of Business Studies' from dual union all
  8  select 4285, 182, 'Bachelor of Commerce (Pass)' from dual union all
  9  select 4291, 182, 'Bachelor of Commerce (Honours)' from dual union all
 10  select 4366, 182, 'Master of Commerce' from dual union all
 11  select  812, 183, 'B.Com. (Hons)' from dual union all
 12  select  829, 184, 'B.Com (Pass)' from dual
 13  /

Table created.

SQL> create table institute_course_category (category_id,institute_id,course_id)
  2  as
  3  select 47, 167, 1134 from dual union all
  4  select 47, 167, 1135 from dual union all
  5  select 47, 167, 1136 from dual union all
  6  select 47, 167, 1137 from dual union all
  7  select 47, 182, 4283 from dual union all
  8  select 47, 182, 4285 from dual union all
  9  select 47, 182, 4291 from dual union all
 10  select 47, 182, 4366 from dual union all
 11  select 47, 183,  812 from dual union all
 12  select 47, 184,  829 from dual
 13  /

Table created.
```

I created those four tables such that your query gives the same result set as in your question:

```
SQL> SELECT inst.*
  2    FROM ( SELECT ROWNUM AS r
  3                , b.name INSTNAME
  4                , ICC.INSTITUTE_ID
  5                , ICC.COURSE_ID
  6                , c.name INSTCOURSE
  7             FROM INSTITUTE_COURSE_CATEGORY ICC
  8                , INSTITUTE a
  9                , MEMBER b
 10                , INSTITUTE_COURSE c
 11            WHERE ICC.CATEGORY_ID  = 47
 12              AND ICC.INSTITUTE_ID = a.id
 13              AND ICC.INSTITUTE_ID = c.institute_id
 14              AND ICC.COURSE_ID    = c.id
 15              AND a.member_id      = b.id
 16         ) inst
 17   WHERE inst.r BETWEEN 1 AND 10
 18  /

  R INSTNAME                             INSTITUTE_ID  COURSE_ID INSTCOURSE
--- ------------------------------------ ------------ ---------- ------------------------------------------------------------------
  1 Asia Pacific Institute Of Management          167       1137 Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking & Financial Services)
  2 Asia Pacific Institute Of Management          167       1136 Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)
  3 Asia Pacific Institute Of Management          167       1135 Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Marketing)
  4 Asia Pacific Institute Of Management          167       1134 Post Graduate Diploma in Management
  5 University of Delhi                           182       4366 Master of Commerce
  6 University of Delhi                           182       4291 Bachelor of Commerce (Honours)
  7 University of Delhi                           182       4285 Bachelor of Commerce (Pass)
  8 University of Delhi                           182       4283 Bachelor of Business Studies
  9 Acharya Narendra Dev College                  183        812 B.Com. (Hons)
 10 Aditi Mahavidyalaya                           184        829 B.Com (Pass)

10 rows selected.
```

Now the XML query is:

```
SQL> select xmlelement
  2         ( "Root"
  3         , xmlelement
  4           ( "INSTITUTE"
  5           , xmlagg(xmlforest(id,name,courses))
  6           )
  7         ).extract('/') your_xml
  8    from ( select i.id
  9                , m.name
 10                , xmlagg
 11                  ( xmlelement
 12                    ( "COURSE"
 13                    , xmlforest(ic.id,ic.name)
 14                    )
 15                  ) courses
 16             from institute i
 17                  inner join member m on (i.member_id = m.id)
 18                  inner join institute_course ic on (ic.institute_id = i.id)
 19                  inner join institute_course_category icc on (icc.institute_id = ic.institute_id and icc.course_id = ic.id)
 20            where icc.category_id = 47
 21            group by i.id
 22                , m.name
 23         )
 24  /

YOUR_XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<Root>
  <INSTITUTE>
    <ID>167</ID>
    <NAME>Asia Pacific Institute Of Management</NAME>
    <COURSES>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>1137</ID>
        <NAME>Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking &amp; Financial Services)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>1136</ID>
        <NAME>Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>1135</ID>
        <NAME>Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Marketing)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>1134</ID>
        <NAME>Post Graduate Diploma in Management</NAME>
      </COURSE>
    </COURSES>
    <ID>182</ID>
    <NAME>University of Delhi</NAME>
    <COURSES>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>4366</ID>
        <NAME>Master of Commerce</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>4291</ID>
        <NAME>Bachelor of Commerce (Honours)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>4285</ID>
        <NAME>Bachelor of Commerce (Pass)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>4283</ID>
        <NAME>Bachelor of Business Studies</NAME>
      </COURSE>
    </COURSES>
    <ID>183</ID>
    <NAME>Acharya Narendra Dev College</NAME>
    <COURSES>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>812</ID>
        <NAME>B.Com. (Hons)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
    </COURSES>
    <ID>184</ID>
    <NAME>Aditi Mahavidyalaya</NAME>
    <COURSES>
      <COURSE>
        <ID>829</ID>
        <NAME>B.Com (Pass)</NAME>
      </COURSE>
    </COURSES>
  </INSTITUTE>
</Root>


1 row selected.
```

Here is the documentation for the functions used:

[XMLElement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions242.htm)
[XMLForest](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions244.htm#SQLRF06169)
[XMLAgg](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions235.htm#sthref1764)

Note that I used `.extract('/')` just for pretty-printing. You can leave that off.

And, just because your current query is only two levels deep, you can shorten the query somewhat by using the query below. However, when your have more than two levels, you'll have to use the inline variant which you can easily expand.

```
SQL> select xmlelement
  2         ( "Root"
  3         , xmlelement
  4           ( "INSTITUTE"
  5           , xmlagg
  6             ( xmlforest
  7               ( i.id
  8               , m.name
  9               , xmlagg
 10                 ( xmlelement
 11                   ( "COURSE"
 12                   , xmlforest(ic.id,ic.name)
 13                   )
 14                 ) as "COURSES"
 15               )
 16             )
 17           )
 18         ).extract('/') your_xml
 19    from institute i
 20         inner join member m on (i.member_id = m.id)
 21         inner join institute_course ic on (ic.institute_id = i.id)
 22         inner join institute_course_category icc on (icc.institute_id = ic.institute_id and icc.course_id = ic.id)
 23   where icc.category_id = 47
 24   group by i.id
 25       , m.name
 26  /
```

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Rob.

Comment: I need something like this but needs to run on SQL Server too.

Comment: Can you help on this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49259105/display-the-hierarchy-in-xml

Answer (score 2):

In order to obtain more or less this result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<institute>
  <id>167</id>
  <name>Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement</name>
  <courses>
    <course>
      <id>1136</id>
      <name>Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)</name>
    </course>
    <course>
      <id>1138</id>
      <name>Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking &amp; Financial Services)</name>
    </course>
  </courses>
  <id>182</id>
  <name>University of Delhi</name>
  <courses>
    <course>
      <id>4283</id>
      <name>Bachelor of Business Studies</name>
    </course>
  </courses>
</institute>
```

you could do something like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;
import org.dom4j.Element;
import org.dom4j.io.OutputFormat;
import org.dom4j.io.XMLWriter;

public class Dom4JTest {

    // DATA SET ORDERED BY INSTITUTE, COURSE (COULD BE THE ID)

    // 3 Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement 167 1136 Post Graduate Diploma in Management
    // (International Business) New Delhi Delhi India
    // 4 Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement 167 1138 Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking &
    // Financial Services) New Delhi Delhi India
    // 5 University of Delhi 182 4283 Bachelor of Business Studies New Delhi Delhi India

    private static List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    static {
        data.add(new String[] { "3", "Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement", "167", "1136",
                "Post Graduate Diploma in Management (International Business)", "New Delhi", "Delhi", "India" });
        data.add(new String[] { "4", "Asia Pacific Institute Of Mangement", "167", "1138",
                "Post Graduate Diploma in Management (Banking & Financial Services)", "New Delhi", "Delhi", "India" });
        data.add(new String[] { "5", "University of Delhi", "182", "4283", "Bachelor of Business Studies", "New Delhi", "Delhi", "India" });

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();
        Element root = document.addElement("institute");

        String id = null;
        Element coursesElement = null;

            // here the iteration over dataset, of course the result will not be just string but the idea will be the same...
        for (String[] strs : data) {
            if (id == null || !id.equals(strs[2])) {
                id = strs[2];
                root.addElement("id").addText(id);
                root.addElement("name").addText(strs[1]);
                coursesElement = root.addElement("courses");
            }
            Element course = coursesElement.addElement("course");
            course.addElement("id").setText(strs[3]);
            course.addElement("name").setText(strs[4]);
        }

        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(System.out, format);
        writer.write(document);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a POJO and then use the JAXB API to convert it to XML.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle can create XML from a query natively

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm

I would guess that this will be the fastest way to do it