# Display the hierarchy in XML

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have the following table:

**Employee (id int,name varchar,managerid int)**

```
   ID   NAME   MANAGERID
    1    A       2
    2    B       4
    3    C       4
    4    D      NULL
```

**Desired Output:**

```
<Node name="D" id="4">
   <Node name="B" id="2">
    <Node name="A" id="1">
    </Node>
   </Node>  
  <Node name="C" id="3">
  </Node>
</Node>
```

Now, I know this is nothing but **Depth First Search** so I've done following:

```
WITH t1(id,name,managerid) AS (
  -- Anchor member.
  SELECT id,
         name,
         managerid
  FROM   employee
    WHERE  managerid IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  -- Recursive member.
  SELECT t2.id,
         t2.name,
         t2.managerid
  FROM   employee t2, t1
  WHERE  t2.managerid = t1.id
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order1
SELECT id,
       name,
       managerid
FROM   t1
ORDER BY order1\\
```

And **output** of above query is :

```
   ID  NAME MANAGERID
    4   D    NULL
    2   B    4
    1   A    2
    3   C    4
```

Now, I don't know how to convert this output into xml version displayed earlier.

I know there are functions like `XMLElement`, `XMLAGG` etc but i don't know how to use that in this sort of hierarchical query.

Note : Currently, I am doing this in **Oracle** but if another RDBMS has easier way to solve this then I am all for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with DBMS_XMLGEN.newcontextfromhierarchy and CTE if you emulate `level` column of `connect by`:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLGEN.getXML(DBMS_XMLGEN.newcontextfromhierarchy('
with employee as (
  select 1 id, ''A'' name, 2 managerid from dual union all
  select 2 id, ''B'' name, 4 managerid from dual union all
  select 3 id, ''C'' name, 4 managerid from dual union all
  select 4 id, ''D'' name, null managerid from dual 
)
, t1(lvl,id,name,managerid) AS (
  -- Anchor member.
  SELECT 1 as lvl,
         id, 
         name,
         managerid
  FROM   employee
    WHERE  managerid IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  -- Recursive member.
  SELECT t1.lvl+1 as lvl, 
         t2.id, 
         t2.name,
         t2.managerid
  FROM   employee t2, t1
  WHERE  t2.managerid = t1.id
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET order1
SELECT lvl, xmlelement("Node", xmlattributes(name AS "name", id AS "id"))
FROM   t1
ORDER BY order1
')) 
FROM dual
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Node name="D" id="4">
  <Node name="B" id="2">
    <Node name="A" id="1"/>
  </Node>
  <Node name="C" id="3"/>
</Node>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy, like so:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxmltype(dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy('
WITH sample_data AS (SELECT 1 ID, ''A'' NAME, 2 managerid FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 2 ID, ''B'' NAME, 4 managerid FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 3 ID, ''C'' NAME, 4 managerid FROM dual UNION ALL
                     SELECT 4 ID, ''D'' NAME, NULL FROM dual)
select level 
       , xmlelement("node" 
       , XMLAttributes(name as "name",
                       id as "id")
       ) 
FROM   sample_data
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = managerid
START WITH managerid IS NULL
  ')) from dual;
```

which returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<node name="D" id="4">
  <node name="B" id="2">
    <node name="A" id="1"/>
  </node>
  <node name="C" id="3"/>
</node>
```

You would need to replace the query inside the `dbms_xmlgen.newcontextFromHierarchy()` call with your actual query.

Comment: Shall I write from `Select level,...` as I already have data stored in table or do I need the first select as well?

Comment: You’d replace the query inside the function call with your query.

Comment: I've tried it and it showing right results but showing same result multiple times. Can you pls have a look at it? :  http://rextester.com/QPTT9910

Comment: It's because your outer query is selecting from employee; the outer query needs to be selecting from dual, since you're passing your actual query into the function call, which you only need to run once.

Comment: if i do that then i am getting this error : 
`The following words are not allowed to appear together in one script: create table dual`

Comment: That doesn't sound like a built-in Oracle error; seems like someone has written a rule that you're somehow violating. You'd have to investigate that on your side. Selecting from dual is perfectly legal everywhere I've worked!

Comment: yeah, I got it...It must be a restriction of rextester itself. Thank you for the help.